# How do I calculate timer intervals for monthly scheduling?

Tags: c#, datetime, intervals

I'm building a Windows Service, and I want it to process a bunch of different background tasks at configurable intervals.

I'm having a hard time working out how to calculate the length of time that the timer needs to wait before kicking off some task.

I store a `StartDate` against the task, and an interval type: daily, weekly, monthly, etc. I've nailed daily, but can't work out how to do monthly...

The rules are:

- If the `StartDate` is in the future, then wait the length of time between `Now` and the `StartDate`.
- If the `StartDate` is in the past, then start the task at the same day-of-month/time as the `StartDate` but in the current/next month. So if the `StartDate` is March 15th at 09:00 and today is May 25th then the next time the task should run is June 15th at 09:00.

I have got so far with this. Here is a test app, which takes a number of test cases and tries to calculate the number of hours between the current time (as per the test case) and the fixed start time of the task:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main() {

        // Test cases
        var times = new Dictionary<DateTime,TimeSpan> {
            { new DateTime(2016, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(2016)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 3, 5, 3, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(1926)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 3, 5, 9, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(1920)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 3, 5, 15, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(1914)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 3, 24, 3, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(1470)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 3, 24, 9, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(1464)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 3, 24, 15, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(1458)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 4, 19, 9, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(840)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 4, 24, 3, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(726)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 4, 24, 9, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(720)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 4, 24, 15, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(714)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 4, 24, 21, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(708)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 5, 6, 3, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(438)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 5, 24, 3, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(6)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 5, 24, 9, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(0)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 5, 24, 15, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(738)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 5, 26, 3, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(702)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 5, 26, 9, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(696)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 5, 26, 15, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(690)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 6, 24, 3, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(6)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 6, 24, 9, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(0)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 6, 24, 15, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(714)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 7, 6, 3, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(438)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 7, 6, 9, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(432)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 7, 6, 15, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(426)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 7, 24, 3, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(6)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 7, 24, 9, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(0)},
            { new DateTime(2016, 7, 24, 15, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromHours(738)},

        }; 


        var startTime = new DateTime(2016, 05, 24, 09, 00, 00);
        var last = times.First().Key;


        foreach (var time in times) {

            var now = time.Key;
            var expected = time.Value;

            var timer = startTime.TimeOfDay - now.TimeOfDay;

            if (now <= startTime)                   
                timer += TimeSpan.FromDays((startTime.Date - now.Date).TotalDays);
            else 
                timer += TimeSpan.FromDays((now.Date.AddMonths(1) - now.Date).TotalDays);                   

            if (last.Date != now.Date) Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"{now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} -> {startTime:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} = {timer:dd\\.hh}   {(timer != expected ? "EXPECTED " + expected.ToString("dd\\.hh") : "CORRECT       ")}");

            last = now;

        }           
    }       
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
2016-03-01 09:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 84.00   CORRECT       

2016-03-05 03:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 80.06   CORRECT       
2016-03-05 09:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 80.00   CORRECT       
2016-03-05 15:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 79.18   CORRECT       

2016-03-24 03:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 61.06   CORRECT       
2016-03-24 09:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 61.00   CORRECT       
2016-03-24 15:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 60.18   CORRECT       

2016-04-19 09:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 35.00   CORRECT       

2016-04-24 03:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 30.06   CORRECT       
2016-04-24 09:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 30.00   CORRECT       
2016-04-24 15:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 29.18   CORRECT       
2016-04-24 21:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 29.12   CORRECT       

2016-05-06 03:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 18.06   CORRECT       

2016-05-24 03:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 00.06   CORRECT       
2016-05-24 09:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 00.00   CORRECT       
2016-05-24 15:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 30.18   CORRECT       

2016-05-26 03:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 31.06   EXPECTED 29.06
2016-05-26 09:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 31.00   EXPECTED 29.00
2016-05-26 15:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 30.18   EXPECTED 28.18

2016-06-24 03:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 30.06   EXPECTED 00.06
2016-06-24 09:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 30.00   EXPECTED 00.00
2016-06-24 15:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 29.18   CORRECT       

2016-07-06 03:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 31.06   EXPECTED 18.06
2016-07-06 09:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 31.00   EXPECTED 18.00
2016-07-06 15:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 30.18   EXPECTED 17.18

2016-07-24 03:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 31.06   EXPECTED 00.06
2016-07-24 09:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 31.00   EXPECTED 00.00
2016-07-24 15:00 -> 2016-05-24 09:00 = 30.18   CORRECT
```

As you can see it goes a bit wrong towards the end. What are the calculations I need to work out the number of hours correctly?

Comment: Isn't `TimeSpan.FromDays((a - b).TotalDays)` equivalent to `(a-b)`?

Comment: @IanMercer: Probably... I have tried many many things and its just me playing around with the calculations without finally optimising it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
foreach (var time in times)
{
    var now = time.Key;
    var expected = time.Value;                
    TimeSpan timer;
    if (now <= startTime) {
         // no need to do anything here - just substract
         timer = startTime - now;
    } 
    else {
         // normalize start time to current month
         var normalized = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
         if (normalized >= now) {
               // normalized date is later in the same month - substract
               timer = normalized - now;
         }
         else {
               // normalized date is before current - move to next month
               timer = normalized.AddMonths(1) - now;
         }
    }                

if (last.Date != now.Date) Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"{now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} -> {startTime:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} = {timer:dd\\.hh}   {(timer != expected ? "EXPECTED " + expected.ToString("dd\\.hh") : "CORRECT       ")}");
    last = now;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Tested and works exactly as needed :)